# Using node in a heroku release phase command

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to use Heroku release phase to automate DB migrations, as suggested by the docs, but it appears that running a node command is not supported out of the box.

If I use `heroku run bash` to inspect the kind of one-off dyno I think the release phase is provided with, node and it's like (yarn, etc) aren't available. My DB migrations are done as node commands, so it's putting a bit of a roadblock in front of me.

Is there a way of automatically using a node-friendly dyno for the release phase, or do I need to create a bash script which installs node and executes the command? Easy enough to do, but hopefully there's a less fiddly option.

**Edit**

Not a heroku issue, but a buildpack issue. I was using a buildpack for monorepos which wasn't copying the `.heroku` directory into the root, or add its contents to `$PATH`. Some full paths in `Procfile` and it's looking good. Now to work out if I can make some changes to the buildpack.

Answer (score 0):

The one-off dyno that runs your [Release Phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) should be able to run anything in your [slug](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler). From your question, it sounds like you don't have node in your slug. In that case the solution is easy. Simply add a [node.js heroku buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) to your app. See [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) how to do that easily.

Comment: Turns out it's a $PATH issue, basically, and combined with a monorepo buildpack.